# Reuse extract a column of a subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`asset_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`published` tinyint
)

CREATE TABLE `content` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`asset_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`title` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`catid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
)
```

'catid' in the content table is storing the category this content belongs too (i.e. the 'id' in the categories table)
Now, I want to extract a list of 'valid' assets (both categories and content). I use the following query, which list all 'published' categories and the content within them.

```
SELECT asset_id, title 
FROM (SELECT asset_id, title FROM categories WHERE published=1) AS ca 
     UNION ALL 
     (SELECT asset_id, title FROM content WHERE catid IN
             (select id FROM categories WHERE published = 1)
     )
```

I can get the desired result. However, you can see that in the query, `FROM categories WHERE published = 1` has been repeated (in the real case, the condition is much longer than just `published = 1`).  Is there a better way to do that?

Since my assets include "images" within "content" within "categories", I need to repeat the whole bunch of condition in each subquery for `UNION ALL`. It's like hell to debug the query.

I am thinking whether there is a way to do `select id, asset_id, title from categories ... AS ca` and then extract the 'id' columns as a set for the second subquery `FROM content WHERE id IN ca.id` (of course this is not working).   I tried "WITH" but Mysql does not support it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: do you have any experience with the JOIN syntax ?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help. Please see my comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `JOIN` solution is probably the *best* way to go...

... but if you want to keep the *subquery* syntax (say, for readability), why not reorganized it?

*If* I understand it well, you need all the categories having "published=1" and all the content belonging to such categories (according to `asset_id`). So the following query should produce *almost* the same result (one more column):

```
SELECT asset_id, title 
FROM (SELECT asset_id, title, id FROM categories 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT asset_id, title, catid FROM content
     ) AS s
     WHERE s.id IN (select id FROM categories WHERE published = 1)
```

Note I typed directly on SO. Please forgive typos and other errors of syntax...

From a performance point of view, this is probably not very good, as I bet it will require a temp table + filesort. But I'm not sure a join will perform better with that respect as you require an `UNION` of two tables...

---

If for some reason it is *too* expensive to examine the table `categories` twice *and* if the expected result is relatively small, maybe you could use a temporary table/view to hold the intermediate results of the query (you might even wish to use `ENGINE MEMORY`).

Its very difficult to tell is this is more efficient or not than the original query. This will depend of many factors. Anyway, using a `JOIN` this time:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cache ENGINE MEMORY
 AS SELECT categories.asset_id as cat_aid, categories.title AS cat_t, categories.id AS cat_i,
       content.asset_id as con_aid, content.title AS con_t, content.catid AS con_i
  FROM categories
  LEFT JOIN content
  ON content.catid = categories.id
  WHERE categories.published = 1;
```

Obtaining the desired results is just a matter of `SELECT ... UNION ...` on that table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat_aid, cat_t FROM cache
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT con_aid, con_t FROM cache;
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/32ee4/2

Comment: Thank you very much. Your query is cleaner. But still cannot solve the problem. (Please see my comment for jaczes's solution).  Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @OliverLeung Thank you for your comment. I missed the point, as I was thinking that your main issue was to avoid to use twice the potential *index*/*linear search* introduced by the `WHERE` clause. If this is *accessing* the table ̀`categories` that is expensive, maybe you should look at `TEMPORARY TABLE`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
SELECT asset_id, title 
FROM  categories WHERE published=1
    UNION ALL 
SELECT co.asset_id, co.title FROM content co
left join categories  ca
on co.catid = ca.id 
WHERE ca.published =1;
```

You should provide some simple data by sqlfiddle.com. There is also question if there You do have indexes/PK/FK and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I do agree that `JOIN` looks better. However, it doesn't solve the problem of have the filtering condition repeat in the query. (As I mentioned, the condition is much longer than simply 'published = 1' in my real case). Even worse, when my 'asset' includes 'images' within 'content' within 'categories'. i.e. there will be 2 UNION ALL to combine the 3 asset lists (cat., content, img), with `FROM content co left join categories  ca on co.catid = ca.id WHERE ca.published =1` repeats again in the 3rd list. I guess the conclusion is that there's no other way to avoid such repetition.